# How do I align an item to the bottom of a full screen landing page?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

To clarify, I have positioned a title in the centre of a full-screen landing page. I would now like to place another item (let's say a `div`) at the bottom of the page. It would  look  something like this,

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|              TITLE              |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|             button              |
+---------------------------------+
```

My current layout looks like this

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|              TITLE              |
|              button             |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

I am using a flexbox that covers the page and  I would like to find out if I could position the button at the bottom without using any absolute positioning. This is my current setup,

```css
.container {
  margin: none;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    TITLE
  </h1>
  <div class="bottom">
    <button>I should be at the bottom</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the bottom div out of the container (following it) and use a negative `margin-top` value (adjust value as desired) and text-centering on it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: none;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.bottom {
  margin-top: -3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    TITLE
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <button>I should be at the bottom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure there's a cleaner solution, but if you add another div you can easily cheat with `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
html, body {height: 100% }

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <h1 class="title">
      TITLE
    </h1>
    <div class="bottom">
      <button>I should be at the bottom</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your .container position to relative,
your .button position set to absolute and apply `bottom: 0`. This should work.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without setting position to absolute?

Comment: Why can't you set an absolute position? Anyway, you can apply style `justify-self: flex-end` or `align-self: flex-end`. Just learn the flexbox basics. Or you can apply style to your button `margin-top: auto` (should work in some cases). Or you can make your title a big size and center it inside, button will come after it.